# How do you swig from std::optional<std::string> to java String?

Tags: java, android, swig

To preface this, I had no idea swig existed until recently. How it works is baffling me. I am slowly learning but it's stumping me how I might go from an std::optional to a String.

I have included:

```
%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_array.i>
%include <std_shared_ptr.i>
%include "const_std_vector.i"
%include "std_optional.i"
```

But when I run swig with just that I have a method that SWIGs into

```
public SWIGTYPE_p_std__optionalT_std__string_t getShowId()
```

Which seems like it's not working at all.

I discovered that if I create a template

```
%template(ShowIdOpt)std::optional<std::string>;
```

That I at least get a Java class that I can call get() to get a SWIGTYPE_p_std__string which seems like sorta the right thing. There are other classes that, if they return a std::string, the swig converts that to String properly, but that doesn't seem to chain together.

Any help would be pretty awesome. Thanks.

Comment: how is this related to java?

Comment: SWIG is used to quickly add hooks from C/C++ code to another language. It's mostly used for scripting languages, but also supports Java. You write a swig file that tells swig how to write the JNI hooks into your C++ code. So you need to understand both the SWIG, and it's JAVA and Android specific rules. I haven't SWIGd before either.